# Can selinux be permissive during the build process?

Tags: android-source, selinux

I downloaded the AOSP code from Ubuntu as below.

`repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-10.0.0_r39`

After that, the downloaded code was built and flashed.

The Pixel 3a booted up successfully.

I tried typing the following in adb shell.

```
# adb shell getenforce
# enforcing`
```

But what I want is to permissive the SELinux state during the build process.

What should I do?

Who tells me to add

`BOARD_KERNEL_CMDLINE += androidboot.selinux=permissive` to **BoardConfig.mk**,

but I couldn't find BoardConfig.mk in the AOSP code I received.

May I know the location of the **BoardConfig.mk** file?

Or, if there is another way, please let me know.

**To summarize:**

```
I want to set SELinux into permissive mode during the build process.
```

Answer (score 0):

`BoardConfig.mk` is a device specific file so it is found in `device/google/bonito/sargo/BoardConfig.mk` path.

https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/android-10.0.0_r39:device/google/bonito/sargo/BoardConfig.mk

Comment: oh thanks for the reply I'll try. Why is there a sargo in the bonito directory?

Comment: This is because they share common architecture and very much common device specific architecture.